# Connecting database from another network

Tags: sql-server, network

We have a database in our server at work, and we can connect the database if we are connected to same network with server. I want to connect from my home. How can I do this?

I have tried couple of connection strings. But none of them worked.

Thank you all
Best Regards

Comment: Have you considered remoting into your desktop at work? If you're a newb with setting up a VPN and don't want to expose SQL to the internet, using RDP would be simples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, this is an option too. In fact we want to connect the database though MATLAB or Python. RDP could be useful sometimes but it's not my main wish

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the server is behind a firewall and you are being blocked. So unless your SQL Server is public, which I really hope that it is not - then you will need to speak to your Network Administrators and request external access via VPN or some other method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, we don't have a Network Administrator however I can do anything that is necessary. I believe only option left is VPN. I previously look up little bit but can't find any tutorial for newbies. Do you have such a knowledge?